# Chat room error

Tags: bug, status-completed

Today I received chat room privileges. The documentation said:

> How do I create a new chat room?
>
> Visit
>
> http://chat.wordpress.stackexchange.com

---

However, when I click on that link, it forwards to: http://chat.wordpress.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/
which is a server error page. Presumably, either something's wrong with chat, or with the documentation.

Comment: @Jeff - can mark complete if you like; I lack access.

Answer (score 1):

The landing page is now in place across all SE sites; we'll get the chat *itself* released as soon as we're happy with the changes we are making (to support consolidated chat).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the chat rooms are not enabled yet across all sites. If you want to have an idea what it looks like, you can go to the [Meta Stack Overflow chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/) (I think you can visit them, even if you have no rep there). The documentation should be updated, but maybe they won't do this if the chat is about to be enabled soon.

Answer (score 0):

Good point -- we're planning to consolidate per-site chats  at chat.stackexchange.com. We'll set up a landing page for that so at least it's not "page not found".